# How can i make this run faster?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, producer-consumer

Can I do threads instead of tasks to make this run faster?
I'm trying to get 114000 products into the database. As my code is right now I get about 100 products into the database a minute.

My Tasks (producers) each scrape an `XML` File which contains a product data, packages it in the Product class, then queue's it for the consumer.

my Consumer takes each product from the queue and puts it into the database 1 at a time. I use Entity Framework so it's not safe for threading.

```
public static void GetAllProductsFromIndexes_AndPutInDB(List<IndexModel> indexes, ProductContext context)
{
    BlockingCollection<IndexModel> inputQueue = CreateInputQueue(indexes);
    BlockingCollection<Product> productsQueue = new BlockingCollection<Product>(5000);

    var consumer = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (Product readyProduct in productsQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            InsertProductInDB(readyProduct, context);
        }
    });

    var producers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
        .Select(_ => Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (IndexModel index in inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Product product = new Product();
                byte[] unconvertedByteArray;
                string xml;
                string url = @"https://data.Icecat.biz/export/freexml.int/en/";

                unconvertedByteArray = DownloadIcecatFile(index.IndexNumber.ToString() + ".xml", url);
                xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unconvertedByteArray);
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

                GetProductDetails(product, xmlDoc, index);

                XmlNodeList nodeList = (xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductFeature"));
                product.FeaturesLink = GetProductFeatures(product, nodeList);

                nodeList = (xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductGallery/ProductPicture"));
                product.Images = GetProductImages(nodeList);
                productsQueue.Add(product);
            }
        })).ToArray();

    Task.WaitAll(producers);
    productsQueue.CompleteAdding();
    consumer.Wait();
}
```

Comment: Profile it to find the bottleneck, then fix that.

Comment: You should batch insert the data to the database rather than one by one.

Comment: You say entity framework is not safe for threading. It is if you use separate context objects for each thread. If, however, you need to save them all in one transaction then you're back to one context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things you *must* do.

Detach each Product entity after you isnert it, or they will all accumulate in the Change Tracker.

Don't call SaveChanges after every product.  Batch up a hundred or so.  Like this:

```
var consumer = Task.Run(() =>
{
    var batch = new List<Product>();

    foreach (Product readyProduct in productsQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        batch.Add(readyProduct);
        if (batch.Count >= 100)
        {
            context.Products.AddRange(batch);
            context.SaveChanges();
            foreach (var p in batch)
            {
                context.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Detached;
            }
            batch.Clear();
        }

    }
    context.Products.AddRange(batch);
    context.SaveChanges();
    foreach (var p in batch)
    {
        context.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }

});
```

If you're on EF Core and your provider supports it (Like SQL Server), you'll even get statement batching.  You should expect several hunderd rows per second using basic best-practices here.  If you need more than that, you can switch to a bulk load API ( like SqlBulkCopy for SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

First, read the [speed rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) to make sure this is even worth investigating.

> Can I do threads instead of tasks to make this run faster?

Extremely unlikely. Multithreading has been used as a cheap way to implement Multitasking for a while, but it is technically only usefull if the task is **CPU bound**. You are doing a DB operation. That one will be Network bound. More likely DB bound (they apply additional bottlenecks as part of their reliabiltiy and concurrency issue prevention).

> Im trying to get 114000 products into the db.

Then your best bet is *not trying to do that in code*. Every DBMS worth it's memory footprint has bulk insert options. Doing that in C# code? That will just make it slower and less reliable.

*At best* you add the Network load to send the data to the DB to the whole operation. At worst, you make it even slower then that. It is one of the most common mistakes with DB's, thinking you can beat the DBMS performance with code. It will not work.